# convert text in an image to readable text

Tags: python, image, image-processing, artificial-intelligence, tesseract

I am using tesseract-ocr to convert text in an image to text..

```
pytesseract -l eng <filepath>image1.jpg
```

because the text size is so small the image output is gibberish.. here is the image..

[image]

from tesseract's documentation: *There is a minimum text size for reasonable accuracy. You have to consider resolution as well as point size. Accuracy drops off below 10pt x 300dpi, rapidly below 8pt x 300dpi. Below an x-height of 10 pixels, you have very little chance of accurate results, and below about 8 pixels, most of the text will be "noise removed".*

My question is: is there a work around for it? changing the DPI or text size in the image?

Comment: You have two good ideas at the end of your post, both of which are supported by the documentation you cite.  What happens when you try those changes?

Comment: i get the exact same output as before.. no difference even in a single character..

Comment: Are you just enlarging the image, or do you have access to the original document to truly alter the text size and DPI?  If you're just enlarging, then you're not adding any information to the image -- hence, the OCR algorithm still fails.  In this case, `tesseract` is simply not strong enough to scan the image for you.

Comment: isnt it possible to enlarge the text size without the original document.. I just have one image that I am working with..